# PHP - Uploading multiple files

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, forms, upload

I'm working on a plugin for wordpress and I want to be able to upload multiple pictures from a form. Right now when I have a form for two pictures and submit it empty, my $_FILES array looks like this:

```
Array (
    [image] => Array ( 
        [name] => Array ( 
            [1] => 
            [2] =>
        ) 
        [type] => Array ( 
            [1] => 
            [2] =>
        ) 
        [tmp_name] => Array ( 
            [1] => 
            [2] =>
        ) 
        [error] => Array ( 
            [1] => 4 
            [2] => 4
        ) 
        [size] => Array ( 
            [1] => 0 
            [2] => 0 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Now the problem is that I want to use wordpress' upload handler, wp_handle_upload. It expects the $_FILES array as an argument, but only with one file. I guess it can only be two arrays deep, not three as mine is. So I'm wondering if there's a way to submit the files one at a time from the $_FILES array. The files have the same key in each array.

EDIT: Changed the post since I learned that the wp_handle_upload wants the $_FILES array as argument.

Comment: Do your file inputs happen to carry a name= like `image[]`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
$files = $_FILES['image'];
foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($files['name'][$key]) {
    $file = array(
      'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
      'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
      'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
      'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
      'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
    );
    wp_handle_upload($file);
  }
}
```

Comment: This got me almost all the way, thank you! I had to change $key in the array to $x, because thats the variable used to increment. Now the only problem is that when I leave a filefield empty it still gets processed through that loop.

Comment: @Toxid: See my update, you can just wrap the whole thing in an `if`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was experimenting with ifs but couldnt figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Toxid if($_FILES['image']['error']<1) { //do something }

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me

```
foreach ($course_video_files['name'] as $key => $value):
                if ($course_video_files['name'][$key]) {
                    $file = array(
                        'name'     => $course_video_files['name'][$key],
                        'type'     => $course_video_files['type'][$key],
                        'tmp_name' => $course_video_files['tmp_name'][$key],
                        'error'    => $course_video_files['error'][$key],
                        'size'     => $course_video_files['size'][$key]
                    );

                    $upload_video_id = MPR_Core::upload_media($file);
                    if( is_int($upload_video_id) ):
                      // if upload is success do something with attachment id
                   
                    endif;
                }
 endforeach;
```

and use this function for uploading

```
function upload_media($file, $post_id = null){
    // handle video upload
    $uploadedfile = $file;
    $upload_overrides = array(
        'test_form' => false
    );

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
    if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {

        if( is_array($movefile) && !empty($movefile) ):

            // $filename should be the path to a file in the upload directory.
            $filename = $movefile['file'];
            //$filename = '/path/to/uploads/2013/03/filename.jpg';

            // The ID of the post this attachment is for.
            $parent_post_id = $post_id;

            // Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
            $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

            // Get the path to the upload directory.
            $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

            // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
            $attachment = array(
                'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
                'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
                'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
            );

            // Insert the attachment.
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );

            // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

            // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

            set_post_thumbnail( $parent_post_id, $attach_id );

            return $attach_id;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;


    } else {
        /*
         * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
         * @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
         */
        //echo $movefile['error'];
        return $movefile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you loop through your files array and then call the upload_handlers?

e.g.

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= count( $_FILES['image']['name']; $i++ ) {
    // just cguessing on the args wp_handle_upload takes
    wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['images']['tmp'][$i], $_FILES['images']['name'][$i] );
}
```

Comment: Good idea, I've thought about this too. After doing a bit of research, I realize I was wrong in my first post. The wp_handle_upload expects the $_FILES array as argument, but only with one file. So I guess it can only be two arrays deep.